# gob: type not registered for interface: map[string]interface {}

Tags: go, gob

`gob` fails to encode `map[string]interface{}`

```
gob: type not registered for interface: map[string]interface {}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Si4hd8I0JE

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func CloneObject(a, b interface{}) []byte {
    buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(buff)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buff)
    err := enc.Encode(a)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("e1: ", err)
    }
    b1 := buff.Bytes()
    err = dec.Decode(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("e2: ", err)
    }
    return b1
}

func main() {
    var a interface{}
    a = map[string]interface{}{"X": 1}
    b2, err := json.Marshal(&a)
    fmt.Println(string(b2), err)

    var b interface{}
    b1 := CloneObject(&a, &b)
    fmt.Println(string(b1))
}
```

Is it possible to encode `map[string]interface{}` in gob?
I am able to encode it with JSON

Answer (score 51, accepted):

add

```
gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Dd3IzJgl0A

Answer (score 10):

Probably yes, but you do have to Register your type beforehand. See http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Register.

The details are documented in http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#hdr-Encoding_Details

(It really does help to look at the Go documentation :-)

Comment: Google returns only 2 pages. This page and go source code: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=gob%3A+type+not+registered+for+interface%3A+map%5Bstring%5Dinterface+%7B%7D&oq=gob%3A+type+not+registered+for+interface%3A+map%5Bstring%5Dinterface+%7B%7D&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22gob:+type+not+registered+for+interface:+map%5Bstring%5Dinterface+%7B%7D%22