# Is there a built in function in go for making copies of arbitrary maps?

Tags: go

Is there a built in function in go for making copies of arbitrary maps?

I would be able to write one by hand but I found out earlier I was looking a similar question when I wanted to make a deep comparison of maps and there seemed to be a function already built in for that! So similarly, maybe I was wondering if there was an built in or some library or package for making deep copies of maps in golang. I am sure I am not the first person to want to make copies of maps in go.

By copy I mean you can create two different variables that reference a different map in memory even though they are the same content wise.

Answer (score 9):

For a more general answer, you can encode your map and decode it in a new variable with [encoding/gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob).

The advantages of this way is that it'll even work on more complex data structure, like a slice of struct containing a slice of maps.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    ori := map[string]int{
        "key":  3,
        "clef": 5,
    }

    var mod bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&mod)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(&mod)

    fmt.Println("ori:", ori) // key:3 clef:5
    err := enc.Encode(ori)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("encode error:", err)
    }

    var cpy map[string]int
    err = dec.Decode(&cpy)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("decode error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("cpy:", cpy) // key:3 clef:5
    cpy["key"] = 2
    fmt.Println("cpy:", cpy) // key:2 clef:5
    fmt.Println("ori:", ori) // key:3 clef:5
}
```

If you want to know more about gobs, there is a [go blog post about it.](http://blog.golang.org/gobs-of-data)

Comment: Is this approach faster or slower than an equivalent approach using the reflection package?

Comment: I spent a little time today implementing this for deep copying map[string]interface{} types in particular, with tests. Here is the code in case it saves time for anyone else: https://gist.github.com/soroushjp/0ec92102641ddfc3ad5515ca76405f4d

The implementation should work for any other Go type with minor tweaks. Also recommend looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934730/gob-type-not-registered-for-interface-mapstringinterface

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no *built-in* one-liner for map deep copy.

However, there is an [iterative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436864/go-copying-all-elements-of-a-map-into-another) as well as a [generic package for deep copy](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy).

Comment: does the generic package for deep copy work for maps?

Comment: @Pinocchio: AFAIK, yes.

Comment: how do you use it? I tried having import "code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy" and it said: prog.go:5: can't find import: "code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy"
 [process exited with non-zero status]

Comment: It looks like that the code is verbose and does not compile under Go 1

Comment: @Pinocchio: I am not near my terminal right now, so I can't test like I'd want to, but have you tried [go get all](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote)?

Answer (score -1):

Copying a map is a few, trivial lines of code. Just write the code and enjoy letting go of the idea that every simple piece of code has to be in a library!

```
original := map[string]int{
    "Hello": 4,
    "World": 123,
}

copy := map[string]int{}
for k, v := range original {
    copy[k] = v
}
```

Comment: While I agree with you in general, a built-in for cloning maps might have performance advantages for large maps: iterative insertion is forced to go through hashing the key, classifying it into a bucket, comparing it with the values in that bucket -- and that is for each pair in the map. Conversely, a built-in could just clone all the internal structures w/o recalculating anything.

Comment: Given the existence of `len` and `append`, `copy` would seem to be an obvious addition for reasons of performance.

Comment: and this is a shallow copy, a deep copy is a bunch more complicated, especially if the map contains itself (or a parent even)

Comment: This answer demonstrates exactly why a built-in would be helpful for performance reasons. The correct copy is not as *trivial* as the author forgot to give the size hint for allocation: `copy := make(map[string]int{}, len(original))`